# Getting custom fields in result of tokenInput

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

I have used jquery plugin "tokenInput" to form a tagged search result.

My code looks like :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/admin/Downloads/loopj-jquery-tokeninput-201d2d1/src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/admin/Downloads/loopj-jquery-tokeninput-201d2d1/styles/token-input.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/admin/Downloads/loopj-jquery-tokeninput-201d2d1/styles/token-input-facebook.css" />


<body>

    <h2 id="theme">Tabs Horizontal</h2>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="demo-input-facebook-theme" name="demo2" />
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='Dashboard.search.searchResult();'> SUBMIT</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var flat_obj = [{_id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
                {_id: 11, name: "Python"},
                {_id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
                {_id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
                {_id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
                {_id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
                {_id: 29, name: "C#"},
                {_id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
                {_id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
                {_id: 41, name: "C"},
                {_id: 43, name: "C++"},
                {_id: 47, name: "Java"}];
            $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput(flat_obj, {
                theme: "facebook",
                tokenValue: "_id"
            });
        });
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard.search.searchResult

```
searchResult : function(){
            $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("get");
            console.log("value : " ,$("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("get"));
        }
```

When I print the output, the result is in the form:

```
id: undefined
name: "Lisp"
```

I need "_id" to be included in search result instead of id.
I tried tokenValue : "_id", but it didn't work..

Need help....!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/boo3bqtc/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Thanks. I guess something was wrong with my version of plugin.